# How to get total amount of revenue from stripe using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to get the total amount of revenue generated in my stripe account because I want to show it to a dashboard.Can someone please tell how can I do this in Nodejs.

I tried doing this but it returns balance is not defined.

````
stripe.balance.retrieve(function (err, balance) {
      console.log(balance);
    });```
````

Comment: your code works fine for me. Did you install the stripe-node package and initialize `stripe`? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage

Comment: Hi, there is not enough code to understand where is  the problem

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me. Can you share the raw and full error message?

Please note that `stripe.balance.retrieve` is for retrieving the balances of your Stripe account as of the time when you make the request. It doesn't provide total revenue of your account since account creation.